# is there a faster way of checking if list[i] of pygame surface has alpha 0

Tags: python, numpy, pygame, surface

I'm making a sprite sheet class in pygame and I'm putting every frame I get from an image in an list.
But, sometimes the sprite sheet has some empty frames.
e.g. I made a image with 2 sprite animation, so I put each one in a row, but the first one is 1 frame bigger than the 2nd one, so the 2nd has a empty frame.

I did this code to check if the frame is empty. I used a reversed loop 'cause most empty frames are at the end of the list, so I can break when any frame is not empty, so then it won't take that much time.

```py
for i in reversed(range(len(frames))):
    frame_alpha_as_array = surfarray.array_alpha(frames[i])

    if np.sum(frame_alpha_as_array) == 0:
        del(frames[i])
    else:
        break
```

But, I would like to know if there is a faster way of doing that, so that it doesn't take much of the cpu/gpu/ram (IDK).

I'm relatively new to programing so don't be too harsh if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @Doyousketch2 wouldn't it be slower? If I understand correctly, it would be checking every single frame when adding to the sprite sheet, and by looping backwards, it only checks the number of empty frames + 1

Comment: I didn't get what you are saying, sorry.

 You mean like save the sprite sheet from photoshop already without the blank spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pygame.surfarray.pixels_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html#pygame.surfarray.pixels_alpha) instead of [`pygame.surfarray.array_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html#pygame.surfarray.pixels_alpha). While `pygame.surfarray.array_alpha()` copies pixel alphas to a 2D array, `pygame.surfarray.pixels_alpha()` refers directly to pixel alphas.

See the documentation of [`pygame.surfarray.pixels_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html#pygame.surfarray.pixels_alpha)

> Create a new 2D array that directly references the alpha values (degree of transparency) in a Surface. Any changes to the array will affect the pixels in the Surface. **This is a fast operation since no data is copied.**
> The Surface this array references will remain locked for the lifetime of the array.

Use [`numpy.any`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) to test whether any array element is greater 0:

```py
if not np.any(surfarray.pixels_alpha(frames[i]) != 0):
```